# Cannot use Truecrypt for Google Drive for PC

Tags: truecrypt, setup, google-drive

I failed to set up a [Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) volume to use it as Google Drive folder.

How can I pass over it?

**Update**

I have succeeded applying Truecrypt for Dropbox folder.

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: No error message indeed. Google Drive keeps showing `syncing 1 of 96` and seems to be like that forever. I try not to use a Truecrypt volume and it works normally.

Comment: OH. Thats simple enough - it can't sync a file thats in use.

Answer (score 1):

Its actually pretty simple, and common to most file syncronisation software - they can't or won't synchronize files that are being written to, or have open handles. Its a 'lazy' way to ensure file integrity, since they can be sure the contents of the file arn't being altered while its being written to. Since google drive is trying to synchronize a single file (your truecrypt volume) while its in use, its waiting for you to be done with it.

Between the nature of encrypted files and syncronisation services, periodically unmounting (and maybe creating a copy) is the only way to get a consistant, working backup off an encrypted file.

Comment: Thank you! I got what you mean. I just feel strange for that. I applied the same method for Dropbox and it works while Google Drive not.

Comment: Dropbox dosen't sync files that are open for me, thats why I worked out this must be it. Maybe they use different ways of handling whether a file is closed or open

Comment: I agree maybe the method to detect a file is `in use` by Google Drive take the Truecript volume into account while Dropbox just care about the idividual file inside that volume

Comment: That would mean dropbox is aware its being written - more likely one checks if its being actively written to , and the other just checks file handles